# How to use Java multithreading for multiple methods in same class?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to Java. I have a method `functionX(List<Object>)` which is called in `functionY` multiple times.

```
class A {
    void functionX(List<Object>){
    ...
    }
    Void functionY {
        while(condition) {
             functionX();
        }
    }
}
```

I have another `class B` where I am calling the method `functionY` in `Class A`.

```
Class B {
    main() {
       A instance = new A();
       instance.functionY();
}
```

Now I want to use multi-threading to execute the method `functionX` for each element in the `List<Object>`. I am confused how to do it. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I recommend to start with the official [Java Tutorial on Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html). You need to understand those concepts as they're not that simple.

Comment: Your class A must implement Runnable interface. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html and then check: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Comment: "...use multi-threading to execute the method..." Not clear what you are asking.  I second what Hein Blöd said: time to read some tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mohan.t, in your q. you have asked you want parallel processing of List elements.

in your problem description, you have not mentioned what it does -- so I am going to make it generic.

```
class A {
    void functionX(List<YourClass> myList){
       ExecutorService exs = Executors.newFixedThreadPool("expected size of list");
        for( Runnable r : myList){
           exs. submit(r);
        }
    exs.shutdown();

    }
    Void functionY {
        while(condition) {
             functionX();
        }
    }
}
```

this will run all your elements in parallel ("expected size of list" - at a time -- that is your degree of parallelism-- how many core and threads/cores you have on your box? ) and once all execution is completed, service will be shutdown. this is the easiest solution...

Note that I have used `List<Runnable>` , your elements need to implement Runnable interface so it can run in the thread.

```
Class YourClass implements Runnable{

   @override
      public void run(){
          ...
          // your logic goes here 
       }
}
```

Check how to create and run threads in java and review Executor framework.

If  those objects are non-modifiable, i.e. if you cant change it to implement runnable-- post back -- we can review more complex options..